# How can I maximize the area of a rectangle given a continuous range of values for the length and width?

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization

All the examples I have for rectangle area maximization problems start by having one of the sides fixed. But suppose I have a continuous range such that length is between A and B and height is between C and D. The tabular/computed solution is readily apparent, but can an exact value be proven?

Comment: $BD$ is the maximum.

Comment: @Sawarnik, it seems that greater/less than signs are interpreted as markup.

Comment: @FelixMarin, can I also maximize the length of the diagonal?

Comment: Both the area and diagonal are increasing functions of length and breadth, so they get maximised when you choose the maximum allowed values.